# React prod build front end not using proxy to access back end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx, fetch

I 've built a react app that runs noermally in dev but when I prod build it the front end fetch requests dont use the proxy I've specified in the package.json file.

fetch request:

```
export const verifyUser = async (user) => {
  console.log(user);
  const newData = await fetch("/login", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ name: user.username, password: user.password }),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
  }).then((res) => res.json());
  return newData;
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://host.docker.internal:8080",
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.17",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
    "postcss": "^7.0.39",
    "postcss-cli": "^9.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17"
  }
}
```

ui Dockerfile:

```
# build environment
FROM node:14.18.1 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY . .
RUN npm ci
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.21.4-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /app/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "nginx","-g", "daemon off;"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  ui:
    build: ./my-app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - api
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

I've tried putting the full address in the fetch call and it did not work
nginx.config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make an effort to search for the solution to your problem online before posting a question on SO. If you take the [tour] and read [ask] you will see that is expected from you. The proxy is not used in production, it's only to make development easier. In production you need to take care of that yourself. This is covered in reacts own documentation.

Comment: Yeah I've searched and read but there are a bunch of things that I can't understand like: can I still use fetch ar do I have to use axios? Is the problem in my nginx file or I can solve it from the package.json file?

Comment: You can use fetch. There are probably 100s of different ways to set this up. What you need to do depends on your setup. The bottom line is basically something like: In development your fetch to `/login` goes to your development server and get forwarded to whatever you specified as proxy. In development `/login` will go to the URL your site is hosted on. Let's say `example.com`, so then fetching `/login` will actually try to fetch `example.com/login`. So you need to make sure that route on your hosting server reaches your API. The most common way is to set up a reverse proxy pass in webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make Nginx pass the calls to your API through to your API container. A common way to do that is to prefix all API requests with /api/, so your /login endpoint becomes /api/login.

If you change your nginx.conf to

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://api:8080/;
    }
}
```

then it'll pass on the requests. That means that you also need to change your fetch call to

```
  const newData = await fetch("/api/login", {
```

Since you always access the api container through the nginx container, there's no need to map the api container port to a port on the host and you can remove that in your docker-compose file

```
  api:
    build: ./api
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```